# Does Azure support Full Page Caching?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

We want to use Microsoft Azure as CDN and caching solution. However, does Azure support full page caching?

By 'full page caching' I mean cache whole HTML document (included all assets).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the page content. Azure CDN Caching is well-suited for locally managing small, static data such as static images, CSS files, and JavaScript files. If it is a static HTML page, it will cache the full page. Dynamic content cannot be cached. Dynamic resources that change frequently or are unique to an individual user cannot be cached.

You could read more details about [how caching works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works).